# TagInspector on Windows - looking for an equivalent that shows character-encoding

Tags: id3, id3v2, id3-tag

So I came across this article, which describes a tool called 'TagInspector'.  Here's the containing article: https://lachlanwetherall.com/2014/09/holden-mylink-and-the-cover-art-conundrum/

The link to TagInspector shown in the article, goes to a Linux-centric website, that offers both Linux and Windows kits for TagInspector.
The bad news (for me) was that both Windows kits (32-bit and 64-bit) contain just a single file, a .exe, and when I run that, on both Win-10 and Win-7 computers, I get 'unknown runtime error 123', when I try to open any MP3 file.
(I sent a msg, via the 'Contact' tab, to that TagInspector distributing site, alerting them to that problem with their Windows'
kits.  I don't know if/when I might ever get a fix for the problem.)

So, MEANWHILE, what my bottom-line issue now is, is how to find some ALTERNATE freeware 'id3-tag'-displaying software that, as this one
does, not only displays the VERSION# of ide-tags, but also shows the
CHARACTER-ENCODING in use.  Specifically, whether the encoding is
ISO8859-1 or UTF16-BOM(Unicode).
[ If you read the article, it shows a screenshot, and explains why
this level of detail is needed, to resolve issues with album-cover
artwork not appearing correctly on certain in-vehicle touch-screen music players. His article pertains to in-vehicle consoles containing
"MyLink" firmware, whereas my vehicle (a 2015 Subaru) contains "StarLink" firmware. ]

So, my question is simply: Can anyone point me to some other id3-tag displaying software that, like TagInspector does additionally show the character-encoding?  I'd want something that is offered in a
Windows-edition.

[ I have been using some freeware called "MP3tag", but I see no way to get it to show/confirm the character-encoding of the id3 tags. ]

TIA...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've resolved this issue to my satisfaction.

(1) I updated an old Linux machine that had been on moth-balls, and
installed the Linux kit offering of TagInspector.  It works fine on Linux
and I was able to confirm the character-encoding of the id3-info in the MP3 files in question.

(2) More importantly, after re-reading the initial article mentioned, it
appears that it must be the 'nature-of-the-beast'...i.e. that id3 version 1
tags are (always) encoded in ISO8859_1, whereas id3v2.x are (always) encoded
in UTF-16_BOM.  As a result, I now see no further NEED to continue to
use TagInspector.  My original app..."Mp3tag" will fulfill my needs
for an id3-tag application.

Cheers...

Comment: You can also use `%_id3v2_character_encoding%` in Mp3tag to display the character encoding.

Comment: No: ID3v1 has no encoding specified, one should only use ASCII, not even ISO-8859-1 (yet in the real world I've even encountered UTF-8). ID3v2.2 and ID3v2.3 can have ISO-8859-1 plus different frames offer also UTF-16 support. ID3v2.4 extends the per frame support to UTF-8 and non-BOM UTF-16BE.